# 1 sql query results into another

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I am trying to get distinct data from a view that I have created from 2 tables

I have a view with the following data

```
emplid  date_and_time   cardreader  empl_first_name empl_last_name
845         2017-12-12 08:38:02.000 GH-ENTRY-01 Amanda  Gill
61811       2017-12-12 08:38:00.000 GH-ENTRY-02 Julie   Moore
61618       2017-12-12 08:36:02.000 GH-ENTRY-01 THOMAS  HOEY
62094       2017-12-12 08:36:01.000 GH-EXIT-03  Mikaela Dawson
56481       2017-12-12 08:35:00.000 GH-ENTRY-02 Chase   Bennett
5134        2017-12-12 08:33:02.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Martin  Byron
51532       2017-12-12 08:33:01.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Gary    Brennan
61996       2017-12-12 08:32:04.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Dylan   Roberts
58447       2017-12-12 08:32:03.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Michael Guy
61931       2017-12-12 08:32:01.000 GH-EXIT-01  Mark    Gibbs
61991       2017-12-12 08:32:00.000 GH-EXIT-02  James   Keysell
41932       2017-12-12 08:31:00.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Mark    Sadowski
40437       2017-12-12 08:27:01.000 GH-ENTRY-05 John    Manning
62094       2017-12-12 08:27:00.000 GH-ENTRY-01 Mikaela Dawson
62094       2017-12-12 08:25:01.000 GH-EXIT-01  Mikaela Dawson
61758       2017-12-12 08:25:00.000 GH-ENTRY-02 Deries  Gordon
62094       2017-12-12 08:24:01.000 GH-ENTRY-01 Mikaela Dawson
51532       2017-12-12 08:24:00.000 GH-EXIT-05  Gary    Brennan
61067       2017-12-12 08:23:02.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Matthew Hutchinson
61185       2017-12-12 08:23:01.000 GH-ENTRY-05 Brendan Mckew
61991       2017-12-12 08:21:01.000 GH-ENTRY-02 James   Keysell
```

I would like to get the most recent record for each `emplid`
so the query above gets me the data `order by date_and_time desc`
but the `emplid` column will have duplicates

so I need to select the distinct `emplid` as follows

```
Select distinct emplid
from [EBI_Interface].[dbo].[GateTimes_EmployeeNames]
```

how do I pass this into the 1st query to only get the distinct `emplid` for the most recent date?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select e1.* 
from [EBI_Interface].[dbo].[GateTimes_EmployeeNames] e1
join (select e21.emplid, max(e21.date_and_time) 'dt' 
        from [EBI_Interface].[dbo].[GateTimes_EmployeeNames] e21
        group by e21.emplid
    ) e2 on e1.emplid=e2.emplid and e1.date_and_time=e2.dt
```

If you want to write it some other way around

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select e.*
from [EBI_Interface].[dbo].[GateTimes_EmployeeNames] e
where e.datetime = (select max(e2.datetime)
                    from [EBI_Interface].[dbo].[GateTimes_EmployeeNames] e2
                    where e2.emplid = e.emplid
                   );
```

The canonical solution is to use `row_number()`, but I think SQL Server does a better job of optimizing this query (with the right indexes).

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22
The multi-part identifier "e2.emplid" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20
The multi-part identifier "e2.date_and_time" could not be bound.